# Android + iOS Apps

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, iphone-app

I want to write the same app for Android and iOS.

I bet you are thinking "that's a great idea!  I would have never thought of having the same app on both platforms!"

Is there a development platform that will make this easy / easier? I am basically looking for something where I can write the app once then hit a button and BAM!  I have an Android version and an iOS version. Does something like that exist; or do I have to do double duty?

Comment: the ux guidelines for iOS and Android are incompatible. https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/overview/themes/ https://developer.android.com/design/ So no, it's not a good idea to make an app that looks the same on both oses.

Answer (score 1):

I was just doing some research here because I wanted to make a game. That's when I came across [Adobe Air](https://www.adobe.com/products/air.html), [Corona](https://coronalabs.com/), and [Unity](https://unity3d.com/). These applications have all cross platform support.

However, I don't think the performance will be as good as with natively developed apps. But I have no experience in that (and still not developing a game).

Comment: There are a few such systems (could you please give links to yours?).

Comment: @Mawg I added the links

Comment: Thans! I was searching of Corona and finding only beer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a few cross platform apps, using different methods.

If you have over $1k burning a hole in your pocket, then I doubt that you can beat [Embarcadero Delphi](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi).

> Delphi™ is the fastest way to write, compile, package and deploy
>   cross-platform native applications.
>
> Delphi is the choice for developers wanting the power, readability and
>   flexibility of the Modern Object Pascal language, coupled with native
>   compilers and component libraries for fast single source code
>   development on Windows, macOS, iOS, Android and Linux.

Code once, run on multiple operating systems. It has an excellent drag & drop UI designer, plus tons of other [features](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/features/develop), as you would expect for the price.

---

[Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) is free and excellent, especially if you want access to the camera, address book, etc.

---

For those that don't require access to the camera's hardware or any software resources (such as contacts), I just go with a browser based solution, as that is most likely to be truly cross-platform.

Personally, I code in Angular Js and use Ajax to communicate over a RESTful API to the server, which I code in PHP, but feel free to find your won solutions (e.q. jQuery & Node.Js)